# How to add Pagination in multiple view type RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, pagination

I want to add `Pagination` in my project but i am not getting how to implement `Pagination` feature in multiple view type `recyclerview` . These is my `MainFragment` class codes

```
    class MainFragment : Fragment(),MainFragmentAdapter.MethodCallBack,ChildInterface,CategoryInterface{

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        backgroundWork()
        networkCall()
    }

    private fun backgroundWork(){
        mainFragmentViewModel.viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            mainFragmentViewModel.getItems()
            mainFragmentViewModel.getRate()
        }
    }

    private fun networkCall(){
       mainFragmentViewModel.mCategory.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           adapter!!.category = it as MutableList<Window>
           adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
       }
        mainFragmentViewModel.mAdvertise.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.advertiseBanner = it as MutableList<Window>
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        mainFragmentViewModel.mGoldList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.gold = it as MutableList<Item>
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        mainFragmentViewModel.mSilverList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.silver = it as MutableList<Item>
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        mainFragmentViewModel.mRate.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.mRate = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        mainFragmentViewModel.womenSection.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.womenSection = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        mainFragmentViewModel.discountBanner.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.myDiscountBanner = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        mainFragmentViewModel.trendingBanner.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.myTrendingBanner = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        mainFragmentViewModel.festivalBanner.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.myFestivalBanner = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        mainFragmentViewModel.menSection.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.menSection = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        mainFragmentViewModel.kidSection.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter?.kidSection = it
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
         }
      }
    }
```

This is my Adapter class code

```
    class MainFragmentAdapter(private val myContext: MainFragment, myCallBack: MainFragment): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (position) {
            13 ->{
                with(holder as NewRecyclerViewBindingHolder){
                    this.bind(category)
                }
            }

            12 -> {
                with(holder as AdvertiseHolder){
                    this.bind(advertiseBanner)
                    methodCallBack.addDotsIndicator(0,binding.linearDot,advertiseBanner.size)
                    binding.myPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener{
                        override fun onPageScrolled(
                            position: Int,
                            positionOffset: Float,
                            positionOffsetPixels: Int
                        ) {

                        }

                        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                            methodCallBack.addDotsIndicator(
                                position,
                                binding.linearDot,
                                advertiseBanner.size
                            )
                        }

                        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

                        }
                    })
                }
              }

            11 -> {
                with(holder as JewelleryPromisesHolder){
                    binding.hallmarkBanner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

              10-> {
                  with(holder as DiamondHolder){
                      if (gold.isNotEmpty() && mRate.isNotEmpty()){
                          this.bind(mRate[0].value!!,"Gold",gold)
                      }
                      binding.navigation.setOnClickListener {
                          methodCallBack.click(gold)
                      }
                  }
            }

            9 -> {
                with(holder as DiamondHolder){
                    binding.diamondRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.jewelleryBanner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.bannerImage.loadImage(myDiscountBanner?.url)
                }
            }

            8->{
                with(holder as GenderHolder){
                    if (womenSection.isNotEmpty()){
                        this.bind(womenSection,"WomenCategory")
                    }
                }
            }

            7 -> {
                with(holder as DiamondHolder){
                    binding.diamondRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.jewelleryBanner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.bannerImage.loadImage(myTrendingBanner?.url)
                }
            }

            6->{
                with(holder as GenderHolder){
                    if (menSection.isNotEmpty()){
                        this.bind(menSection,"MenCategory")
                    }
                }
            }

             5 -> {
                 with(holder as DiamondHolder){
                     binding.diamondRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                     binding.jewelleryBanner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                     binding.bannerImage.loadImage(myFestivalBanner?.url)
                 }
            }

             4->{
                 with(holder as DiamondHolder){
                     if (silver.isNotEmpty() && mRate.isNotEmpty()){
                         holder.bind(mRate[1].value!!,"Silver",silver)
                     }
                     binding.navigation.setOnClickListener {
                         methodCallBack.click(silver)
                     }
                 }
            }

            3 -> {
                with(holder as GenderHolder) {
                    if (kidSection.isNotEmpty()) {
                        this.bind(kidSection,"kid")
                    }
                }
            }
            2->{
                with(holder as JewelleryPromisesHolder){
                    binding.table.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.headerTitle.text = myContext.getText(R.string.jewellery_header)
                }
            }

            1 ->{
                with(holder as JewelleryPromisesHolder){
                    binding.headerTitle.text = myContext.getText(R.string.social_feeds)
                    binding.socialFeeds.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

            else -> {
                with(holder as JewelleryPromisesHolder){

                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = 14

    inner class DiamondHolder (val binding : DiamondBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private var productAdapter : ProductAdapter ?= null

        init {
            productAdapter = ProductAdapter(myContext)
            productAdapter?.setListener(myContext)
            binding.diamondRecycler.apply {
                adapter = productAdapter
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
        }

        fun bind(rate : Int , type : String, productList : MutableList<Item>){
           when(type){
               "Gold" -> {
                   binding.title.text = myContext.getText(R.string.jewellery_gold)
               }
               else -> {
                   binding.title.text = myContext.getText(R.string.jewellery_silver)
               }
           }
            productAdapter?.rate = rate
            productAdapter?.submitList(productList)
        }

    }

    inner class GenderHolder(val binding : DiamondBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private var genderAdapter : SectionAdapter ?= null
        init {
            genderAdapter = SectionAdapter()
            binding.diamondRecycler.apply {
                layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(myContext.requireContext(),3)
                adapter = genderAdapter
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
            genderAdapter?.setListener(myContext)
        }

        fun bind(genderList : MutableList<Window>, genderType : String){
            genderAdapter?.submitList(genderList)
            when(genderType){
                "WomenCategory" -> {
                    binding.title.text = myContext.getText(R.string.women_section)
                    genderAdapter?.setGenderType("women")
                }
                "kid" -> {
                    binding.title.text = myContext.getText(R.string.kidSection)
                    genderAdapter?.setGenderType("kid")
                }
                else -> {
                    binding.title.text = myContext.getText(R.string.men_section)
                    genderAdapter?.setGenderType("men")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class NewRecyclerViewBindingHolder (val binding : NewRecyclerviewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private var categoryAdapter : CategoryAdapter ?= null
        init {
            categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter()
            binding.newRecyclerview.apply {
                adapter = categoryAdapter
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
        }

        fun bind(category : MutableList<Window>){
            categoryAdapter?.submitList(category)
        }
    }

    inner class AdvertiseHolder(val binding : AdvertiseBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private var advertiseAdapter : MonthlyAdapter ?= null

        init {
            advertiseAdapter = MonthlyAdapter(myContext.requireContext())
            binding.myPager.adapter = advertiseAdapter
        }

        fun bind(advertiseList : MutableList<Window>){
            advertiseAdapter?.monthlyList = advertiseList
        }
    }




    inner class JewelleryPromisesHolder(val binding : JewelleryPromisesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    } 
.....
```

I'm retreiving multiple arraylist from database in my `MainFragment` class to update different `ViewHolder` class in my `MainFragmentAdapter` class.
I ain't getting how to add `Pagination` feature in my `MainFragment` class because I am using multiple `ArrayList`. Please anyone tell me how to set up `Pagination` feature in multiple view type Recyclerview.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks , I have edited my question , i have tried to add necessary code now. You can check my code and suggest me if it is there any possible way to add Pagination feature in multiple view type Recyclerview.

Comment: There is still a lot of code and I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5) might help.

Comment: @AlexMamo the resources you gave can't help me bro , I don't have single type array list in my adaptor class , I am working with multiple array list of different types  in my adaptor class . Paginated a RecyclerView with single type array list is not big deal. But I am dealing with multiple array list in my adaptor class and I am confused how to add pagination with all these array lists .